# Pandas DF combine rows based on specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DF:

> ```
> Time   Key   Val 
> 0       1    22 
> 0       2    33 
> 0       11   4 
> 0       12   5 
> 1       1    12 
> 1       2    13 
> 1       11   14 
> 1       12   15
> ```

And I want to generate the following:

> ```
> Time    Key1    Val1    Key2    Val2 
> 0        1       22      2       33 
> 0        11      4       12      5 
> 1        1       12      2       13 
> 1        11      14      12      15
> ```

Based that i have a logic that says that I have two groups of keys:

```
{[1,2],[11,12]}
```

Where should i start in order for me to merge Data Frame rows according to specific logic?

Comment: The keys wont work in python, it's not a dictionary nor a set, can you specify what it is and preferably put in a variable.

Comment: Try running `d = {[1,2],[11,12]}`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keys are a list of lists (see `d` below), we can use `pd.concat` with `Series.isin`:

```
d = [[1,2],[11,12]]
n = len(d[0])
keys = [[x[i] for x in d] for i in range(n)]

df = pd.concat([
    df[df['Key'].isin(l)].set_index('Time').add_suffix(i+1) 
     for i, l in enumerate(keys)
], axis=1
).reset_index()

   Time  Key1  Val1  Key2  Val2
0     0     1    22     2    33
1     0    11     4    12     5
2     1     1    12     2    13
3     1    11    14    12    15
```